# Mouse tracking control codes for terminal using bash

Tags: bash, terminal, mouse, console

I'm making a bash implementation of curses as an expermient for fun. I use infocmp to get the ANSI terminal codes. I'm a bit stuck now at how to enable mouse tracking in a cross-console way. I could just implement http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking manually but I wish there was a more portable way of doing this.

Is there a command like infocmp for mouse tracking codes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really: ncurses makes assumptions, and has built-in support for the most common protocols.  The most-used is for xterm. ncurses uses the `kmous` capability to identify the first few characters of the mouse events, but after that, the button-state and coordinates are from the built-in logic.

Regarding an "infocmp for mouse codes", in principle one might suppose that there would be something like `tparm` (only for *decoding*), the mouse button, whether it is a press or release event, and the coordinates.  However there are only a few varieties of xterm mouse protocol, and for such a *small* number of possibilities it does not seem cost effective to write a *general* decoder.  One that could handle the existing varieties in `bash` would be challenging in any case.